# How to copy duplicates into another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the macro below runs (no errors) but no results are provided. I have an excel book where duplicates are sometimes found in column "E". Those identified as duplicates should be copied to sheet 2. I know my workbook has duplicates in column E, their just not being copied over.

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("a1:R" & .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(c1,RC1)>1,"""",1)"
    .Value = .Value
    If Evaluate("=COUNTBLANK(" & .Address & ")") > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(2, 1)
    .ClearContents
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the cell notation you are using R1C1, your formula

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(c1,RC1)>1,"""",1)"
```

refers only to column A

If you want to change your formula to apply on column E, that would be

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(c5,RC5)>1,"""",1)"
```

I don't know if your dupplicates are on a single column basis or if should concatenate all your column to see if the entire row is a dupplicate. It might be more simple to apply a sql query connection on this. Pivot tables may also help. If you stick to vba, add additional line for each dupplicate formula and process it in the block of code that copy blank formula to the secondary sheet.

Comment: That was the issue, thank you. For now I would prefer to use a macro since this workbook has several that connect together. How can I move the formula from column T to column AZ?

Also, could you recommend a site with examples on SQL Query Connection? I've heard of it, but never done that.

Comment: If you switch your excel configuration in the formula menu from R1C1 notation to A1 notation, it will be easier to change the formula in vba, using debug apply a break point at the line where it writes the formula and look on the spreadsheet, you will see the formula active before it gets deleted by your code. For SQL query connection, google should provide you with the most relevant websites, page 1 query result should help you with keywords just as "examples on SQL Query Connection"